# Spring Data MongoDB: how to get an intersection between two lists with aggregate and SetIntersection

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a collection, where one of the fields is a list of integers:

```
myDocument1:{
   _id: 1,
   bits: [0,1,2,9,11,12,19]

},
myDocument2:{
   _id: 2,
   bits: [0,1,3,6,11,12,16]

}
```

On the other hand, I have a query list of integers, for which I want to check the size of the intersection with each bits list of the documents in this collection. In native MongoDB Query language, I proceed as follows:

```
query: [2,9,11];

{'$project': {
            'intersectionSize': {'$let': {
                'vars': {'common': {'$size': {'$setIntersection': ['$bits', query ]}}},
            }},
        '_id': 1,
        }}
```

... that I after add to my aggregation pipeline (that I can add on demand).

Following the spring-data documentation, I have been trying to use ProjectOperator with SetIntersection:

```
List<Integer> list = [2,9,11];          
ProjectionOperation po = project().and(SetOperators.SetIntersection.arrayAsSet("bits")
               .intersects(query).size().as("intersectionSize");
```

...but the "intersects" doesn't accept any type of arrays or lists.

How can I, using MongoTemplate and Spring-Data encode the intersection and its size between an array from my collection and a query array?

Answer (score 0):

As of spring-data-mongodb v3.0.5, there is no variant of the `SetOperators.arrayAsSet()` that accepts a `List` or other `Collection`.  At this time, `SetOperators.arrayAsSet()` will only accept a String field reference, or an `AggregationExpression`.  I believe this means that you need to use `Literal.asLiteral()` for the `AggregationExpression`.  Perhaps you might try this, or something very similar it, because I have not directly tested it:

```
List<Integer> list = [2,9,11];          
ProjectionOperation po = project()
    .and(SetOperators.SetIntersection.arrayAsSet("bits")
        .intersects(Literal.asLiteral(list)).size())
    .as("intersectionSize");
```

Note that I have also added the missing parenthesis to close the `.and()` part of the projection after the call to `.size()`, which was missing in your question and the other answer that was here at the time that I wrote this.